# check-log plugin pointing to /var/cache/check-log/default/var/log/auth.log instead of /var/log/auth.log

Tags: ubuntu, sensu, auth.log

I am using sensu to track log file alerts. I need to track auth.log. I have used the following in my `config.json`.

> "command": "sudo /etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb -f /var/log/auth.log -q 'fatal' -c 1"

I am hoping to track **hack** attempts made to this server, but the sensu command itself gets into the auth.log, making it a chicken-egg issue.

In the auth.log

```
sudo:    sensu : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb -f /var/log/auth.log -q fatal -c 1
```

How do I run sensu commands and avoid the command being tracked in `auth.log`. Or can I redirect sensu `auth` trackings to a different file ?

**EDIT**

To solve this, I added `sensu` user to `adm` group. And removed the entreies from `sudo visudo` for the `sensu` user. Now, I am still not able to get sensu to report. Wierd, error message I get

> Check failed to run: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/cache/check-log/default/var/log/auth.log, ["/etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb:208:in `initialize'", "/etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb:208:in`open'", "/etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb:208:in `search_log'", "/etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb:134:in`block in run'", "/etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb:128:in `each'", "/etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb:128:in`run'", "/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.0/lib/sensu-plugin/cli.rb:58:in `block in '"]

Notice that I am trying to `check-log` for `/var/log/auth.log`, and the client is trying `/var/cache/check-log/default/var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to run `check-log.rb` with root permissions. Actually, I would highly recommend you don't do any checks which require root permissions at all.

Make sure that */etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb* has execute permissions for all users:

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb
```

And that the file */var/log/auth.log* is readable to all:

```
sudo chmod a+r /var/log/auth.log
```

Change your check to:

```
"command": "/etc/sensu/plugins/check-log.rb -f /var/log/auth.log -q 'fatal' -c 1"
```

Don't forget to restart the server (and possibly also the client) for the change to take effect.

This way you don't need to add the `sensu` user to any group,